# Printing html data loaded from database in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have an **array of JSON objects** loaded from database. There is a certain key in each object which has **html contents**.

I want to display these contents in my view along all of those other stuff. I used ng-html-bind, for that i had `$sce` dependency in my controller. If i put a string in there like `<h1>Trusted html</h1>` it works. But not for my contents.

What i really want is if i put those contents like `$scope.htmlContent = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.content);` it should work and loop all of these one by one in my view where they belong. But its not working.

I also made another array, pushed all of these contents material alone but when i pass them through `$sce.trustAsHtml(trustMe);` something goes wrong.

-----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------

**These are my Objects:**

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

:
Object
8
:
Object
$$hashKey
:
"object:22"
content
:
"<h2>Test data.</h2>
↵"
created_at
:
"2016-08-12 14:12:35"
id
:
9
name
:
"Test"
points
:
4
semester
:
"Eagle Nest"
semester_id
:
6
status
:
0
subject
:
"Android"
subject_id
:
6
updated_at
:
"2016-08-12 14:12:35"
user_id
:
1
__proto__
:
```

**My View**

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="quiz in quizzes">
              <div class="panel-body">
                @ quiz.semester @ <span class="pull-right">Subject: @ quiz.subject @ </span>
                <hr class="blur-line">
                <p class="list-group-item-text list-item">
                <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i>  @ quiz.name @
                </p>
                <p class="details" ng-bind-html="MytrustedHtml"></p>

              </div>
            </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.MytrustedHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.content);
```

Comment: any reason why you're not using `ng-repeat` on your items? here's an example of how I usually do it: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/hp8sbzwf/25/

Comment: could you maybe share the code? Jsfiddle would be awesome

Comment: Is this an array of JSON objects, or an array of objects ? Also, ng-html-bind doesn't exist, ng-bind-html does.

Comment: Please, add a gist, or fiddle, in the other hand, that object should be assigned to a scope key, so it's available to your app, then as @duxfox-- stated use a ng-repeat structure. Kind of $scope.data and then in your html <li ng-repeat="object in data">{{object.somekey}}</li>

Comment: "something goes wrong" doesn't give enough information for troubleshooting.  Also, in general, storing HTML inside JSON for angular is a very bad idea, unless it is specifically user generated content, and even in that case, there are better ways to handle such data.

Comment: You should put more details in the question...

Comment: please check the question i updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter might be a better way to manage this.

```
.filter('rawHtml', ["$sce", function($sce) {
    return function(input) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
    };
}]);
```

And in the markup

```
<p ng-bind-html="MytrustedHtml | rawHtml"></p>
```